# Recognize W,A,S,D Spacebar key pressed in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit, sprite

Im making a `SpriteKit` game but I have this trouble with recognizing when a key is press. I want to specially recognise the keys: `W, A, S, D, spacebar, and ESC`.

For example:

```
if (w is press) {
     //jump
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Its not a language the example. Its just what I want to do.

Comment: The language im looking for is SpriteKit.

Comment: This is accomplished depending on the language you want to implement it. Most have libraries that can capture key events. However, I think you should first do some research on your own before asking this question.

Comment: SpriteKit is a library for iOS, which uses objective-C. I recommend learning how to program in Objective-C first then look at tutorials for this library.

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplish by using the following code:

```
    - (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
        [self handleKeyEvent:event keyDown:YES];
    }

    - (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event {
        [self handleKeyEvent:event keyDown:NO];
    }

    - (void)handleKeyEvent:(NSEvent *)event keyDown:(BOOL)downOrUp {
         NSString *characters = [event characters];
         for (int s = 0; s<[characters length]; s++) {
            unichar oneCharacter = [characters characterAtIndex:s];
            switch (oneCharacter) {
                case 'w':
                    [character jump];
                    break;
                case 'a':
                    [character left];
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    [character right];
                    break;
                case 's':
                    NSLog(@"Down");
                    break;
                case ' ':
                 NSLog(@"Shoot");
                 break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to give credit to: Heyfara (He/She answered this in another question). To see the original Post click here: [How Can I get keyboard input in a SpriteKit Game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049776/how-can-i-get-keyboard-input-in-a-spritekit-game)