# Computer Keyboard Input in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, keyboard, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

Is it at all possible to send keyboard input from my computer keyboard through to an iOS app running in the simulator?

I'm messing around with a SpriteKit game and would like to test using the simulator but given that you play with two thumbs and only have one cursor when controlling the simulator, it's basically impossible. It would be really nice to be able to use something like left/right/up/down/space commands from my keyboard to control a character.

Comment: The simulator already accepts inputs from the keyboard.

Comment: How do I translate that in the app itself - i.e. when a user taps the 'move left' button, I call the moveLeft method. How can I trigger the moveLeft method to be called when I hit the left arrow on my keyboard?

Comment: Are you talking about having an onscreen keyboard displayed, on your iDevice, in order to use it as a movement control for your character(s)?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the *computer* keyboard.

Comment: Not sure how the computer keyboard comes into play on an iDevice but here is a link that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049776/how-can-i-get-keyboard-input-in-a-spritekit-game

Comment: Ahhh that looks promising. Thank you very much.

Comment: The mac keyboard can only be accessed by an OS X project run on your mac, you can add an OS X target if you need. The simulator can get keyboard shortcuts but no raw events (it converts mouse events to touch events behind the scenes) you can use assistive touch in accessibility settings (on the simulator) to add custom touch shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack but you could use a UITextField - implement something like

https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/ios-tutorial-hide-keyboard-after-return-done-key-press-in-uitextfield/

You can grab the value of the text typed from keyboard in textFieldShouldReturn as the text property of the UITextField object.

Comment: Thought about that - wondering if handling key pressed/released is possible this way, rather than typed. My guess is not.