# Why is the keyDown function in Swift not working?

Tags: swift, macos, button, sprite-kit, keydown

I've made my own button class (FKButton) in SpriteKit. I want it to have most of the functions I will need in the future, so it includes shortcut-keys, actions, sounds etc. Everything seems to be working fine except the `keyDown(with event: NSEvent)` function (btw. a "shortcut-key" is a key which has the same effect as pressing the button itself. For example, pressing enter on your keyboard often does the same thing as pressing a button on your screen). I have set both `acceptsFirstResponder` and `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`. The code I've written for the `keyDown` function in my button class goes like this:

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    print("Detected key press: \(event.keyCode).")
    if shortcutKeys.contains(event.keyCode) {
        actionAtClick()
    }
}
```

The class inherits from `SKNode` because I want to add it another class which inherits from `SKScene`. This is the class:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let button = FKButton(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100), text: "Button", fontSize: 40)

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    
        button.shortcutKeys = [36,76]
    
        self.addChild(button)
    
    }
}
```

I've just removed everything irrelevant (e.g. `button.fontColor = NSColor.white` etc.). The correct actions are happening when I click the button with my mouse, but for some reason it does not respond to keyboard input. I do not understand what is wrong. I understand that it might be hard for you as well, but all tips are appreciated. Thank you.

Note: This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned in the comments. I have *not* put my code in AppDelegate like the person in the mentioned post did. Therefore, it did not resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I get keyboard input in a SpriteKit Game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049776/how-can-i-get-keyboard-input-in-a-spritekit-game)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately not.

Comment: What is FKButton?

Comment: shortcutKeys?  What is it?

Comment: Oh FKButton is just the name of the class. The shortcut-keys are the keys you can press on your keyboard that does the same thing as pressing the button. It is often used for sign-up forms: Often you can press enter instead of pressing the actual button, but it does the same thing. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event;`

Is a method inherited from NSResponder class, if your `FKButton` is not a inheritor of NSResponder, you can write `override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent)` with not effect.

Try to put the same method on a different class like `NSViewController` that is an instance of NSResponder, sure you have more luck.

Answer (score 0):

To the answer above; An SKNode DOES subsclass NSResponder. It says so right in Apple's documentation for controlling user interactions with nodes.